# databases are invisible to mysql users with privileges

Tags: mysql, sql, database, privileges

From root on MySql, I created a new user called search using

```
CREATE USER search;
```

Then I granted search the privilege of selecting from the tables of a specific database, 'kichai' with the following code

```
GRANT SELECT ON kichai.* TO 'search'.'%';
```

However when I login to mysql using search and type to show the databases

```
SHOW DATABASES;
```

I see only 'information_schema' and 'test'.

My question is why I can't see the database 'kichai' when logged in as search, because the manual says

```
"You see only those databases for which you have some kind of privilege, unless you have the global SHOW DATABASES privilege."
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-databases.html

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```sql
-- GRANT SELECT ON kichai.* TO 'search'.'%';
GRANT SELECT ON `kichai`.* TO 'search'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```